# Apache2.4- how to serve file as html

Tags: logs, configuration, apache-httpd

I have an apache2.4 server. On some page, I have a link to a log file. **I would like to show the file content in a browser** when the link is clicked, rather that serving the file do download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in .htaccess or apache config.

```
     AddType text/plain .log
```